# A question about the relationship betwen $\limsup$ and $\liminf$

Tags: real-analysis

Can it be shown that $\limsup (-a_n) = - \liminf (a_k)$?  My thought is just to prove that $\sup(-a_n)=-\inf(a_n)$.  This is clearly true intuitively, but can anyone help with a first step on making it formal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let $I$ be the infimum of $(a_n)$, then for all $n$, $a_n\ge I$ and there does not exist a real $h>0$ such that for all $n$, $a_n\ge I+h$.

**Hint:** Now multiply both sides of both inequalities by $-1$. Do you get something resembling the definition of the supremum for $(-a_n)$?

Comment: Once you get to reading this answer, let me know if it was helpful or not.

Comment: Completely helpful.  Why I don't just go back to definitions...  My only question is: is doing this fully rigorous or still a little intuitive?  I don't know why I am inclined towards and $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof; it may just be my default.

Comment: @user102830: This answer on its own is not an entirely rigorous argument, no. It should help you in developing a rigorous proof, though. Basically, first show that $\sup\limits_{n\ge m}(-a_n)=-\inf\limits_{n\ge m}(a_n)$. Then, since the two sequences are equal, take the limit on both sides as $m\to\infty$ and take the $-1$ out of the right side limit to get the equation you mention at the start of your question. Does that help?